# How to manage comments on a large TFS shelvset used for code review?

Tags: tfs, tfvc, tfs-code-review

I am reviewing a large shelveset from another developer in TFS web view, TFS server Version 15.117.26714.0. There are a large number of changes over a large number of files. I have been making comments on specific lines of code and using @ mentions to notify the developer. They are getting the notifications but there is no link to the comment I made and no indication to which file or which line. Likewise if they reply I get a notification but again no indication as to which comment or file where the comment was made.

Is there a better way to manage this back-and-forth for code review? It's very convenient to make the comments in line but hard to track and manage. I know I can filter by comment type but the number of comments is still to large to identify a specific comment easily.

I realise this may not generally be an issue as shelvesets or changesets are typically not so big. This shevleset is big as a result of a first pass of a static analyzer on a large code base.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like this is the default behavior that there is no link to the comment I made and no indication to which file or which line in the notification email.

I tested on TFS server and also on Azure devops cloud service. They have the same results that no links to the files or lines are included in the email.

You can [submit a user voice](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/post.html?space=22) to microsoft development team.  Hope they will improve this feature and provide more detailed information in the notification email.

Alternatively, you can have a try reviewing the code in Visual studio. See [tutorial here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/tfvc/day-life-alm-developer-suspend-work-fix-bug-conduct-code-review?view=azure-devops#request-a-code-review) for reviewing code in Visual Studio.

Comment: Thanks for the link to the tutorial. Will definately check it out. User feedback already submitted here: [link](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/1122449/link-to-related-comment-in-shelveset-comment-notif.html?childToView=1123155#comment-1123155)